# multithreaded using _beginthreadex passing parameters

Tags: multithreading, winapi

Visual Studio C++ 2008

I am using threads. However, I have this warnings and not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
1. unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *) differs in levels of indirection from 'void *(__stdcall *)(void *)'
2. _beginthreadex different types for formal and actual parameters 3

/* Function prototype */
void* WINAPI get_info(void *arg_list)

DWORD thread_hd;
DWORD thread_id;

/* Value to pass to the function */
int th_sock_desc = 0;

/* Create thread */
thread_hd = _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, get_info, (void*) th_sock_desc, 0, &thread_id);
if(thread_hd == 0)
{
    /* Failed to create thread */
    fprintf(stderr, "[ %s ] [ %s ] [ %d ]\n", strerror(errno), __func__, __LINE__);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: (void*) th_sock_desc -> &th_sock_desc ?

Comment: Beware that you have to call CloseHandle() on the return value.  boost::thread could be a better mousetrap here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Thread function that you pass to `_beginthreadex` has a different prototype than the one you pass to `_beginthread`

```
uintptr_t _beginthread( 
   void( *start_address )( void * ),
   unsigned stack_size,
   void *arglist 
);
uintptr_t _beginthreadex( 
   void *security,
   unsigned stack_size,
   unsigned ( *start_address )( void * ),
   void *arglist,
   unsigned initflag,
   unsigned *thrdaddr 
);
```

It's the same as what `CreateThread` expects,

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(
  __in  LPVOID lpParameter
);
```

So you need to change the function signature of your thread proc to

```
unsigned WINAPI get_info(void *arg_list)
```

<strike>remove `WINAPI` and</strike> change the return type.

## Edit :

WINAPI is actually needed, the docs show the wrong prototype for _beginthredex, but they explicitly state that __stdcall is needed.  Your problem is just the return type. Also, the error message, says that __stdcall is expected, so that settles it.

Comment: I was thinking I would need WINAPI as that supports the __stdcall. As _beginthreadex expects that. thanks.

Comment: WINAPI is __stdcall. but _beginthreadex expects __cdecl. CreateThread expects __stdcall.

Comment: _beginthread expects a __cdecl, in _beginthreadex the prototype must be a __stdcall (or __clrcall), so WINAPI is fine.

Comment: No. it isn't.  Please note that I posted the declaration of `_beginthreadex`. Do you see any `WINAPI` or `__stdcall` in there?

Comment: start_address
Start address of a routine that begins execution of a new thread. For _beginthread, the calling convention is either __cdecl or __clrcall; for _beginthreadex, it is either __stdcall or __clrcall.

Read the docs.

Comment: @S.Skov: You're right. It does need __stdcall. The comments say so even though the prototype doesn't.  I've updated my answer.